# Short science fiction story. Human worker in peril on a planet. Surface is covered in shallow water. If he becomes exhausted and lies down, will drown

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, planets

Science fiction short story by Heinlein.

Many humans are working on the surface of an alien planet (possibly Venus.) They are dropped off individually to work. They insist on proof they will be picked up again. Staying out too long is deadly. The surface is covered in shallow water so that an exhausted man lying down to rest will drown. The protagonist is in this situation as the vehicle does not pick him up at the end of his shift. I think I read it in the 80s.

Comment: If only they had heard of the "buddy system"...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

That's Robert Heinlein's *[Logic of Empire](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?46402)* and it was Venus.

> The older clients told grim stories of men who had stood in eighteen inches of water for twenty-four, forty-eight, seventy-two hours, and then drowned horribly, out of their heads from sheer fatigue.

The incident in the story arises when a boss wants to set out a worker without a safety "skiff".

Comment: @JudithJones Great question, I'm enjoying re-reading the story.

Comment: I am enjoying re-reading it too. Thanks.

Comment: Just mine off-topic, probably stupid question. Can you drown in 18 inches of water? Even if you are unconscious, your body will float. If you (at the last moment) lay down in that water on your back, your head should be floating over the surface and breath normally. You'd then die of starvation or dehydration, not drowning. Or maybe there are some monstrous tides on that Venus?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can drown in a bathtub.

Comment: @trejder I read somewhere that you drown in the water when you are unconscious - I can not find a 100% factual source (such as the article I read, it was years ago)  but https://www.quora.com/Do-unconscious-bodies-float-or-sink-in-water concurs

Comment: Well... I was more than sure that (when you are unconscious) you can drown in any body or container that hasn't got enough water to allow you float. So bathtub and even larger rain puddle counts. You can drown unconscious, if you are thrown to that water with a bigger force and anything (like a rock attached to your body) takes you down or prevent you from turning over your back. But, if -- as in this story -- (a) the water is enough to allow you float and (b) you can consciously lay on your back then you shouldn't drown theoretically forever. At least that's what I thought until today.

Comment: Note that I wrote in my initial comment that (in the last moment of your strengths weakening) you are  _consciously_ going to lay on your back. That's seems feasible based on the story's description provided here and that's the key point in my comment.

Comment: @trejder: Yes, I suspect you might get lucky and survive falling asleep if the water is calm and you get into a position where you're floating on your back.  It would still be risky.  It could be a lot less risky if you had a flotation collar on your neck to keep your head out of water.  You don't need a full life-jacket since some of your body weight can rest on the ground while your head is out of water (not lifting itself via bouyancy), so this can be light-weight and maybe inflatable to avoid bulk: basic safety equipment for this environment, especially alone without a backpack as pillow.

Comment: What happens, @trejder, if you happen to roll on your side and take a deep breath? Only takes about 3" of water then...

Comment: @FreeMan The story is about totally exhausted man. Such person for sure won't roll on their side on their own. As being totally tired, will lie on their back until forever (until dying from starvation). 3'' / 8 cm of water isn't enough to float or roll on a side without willing to do so. However, the original story says about 18" and that makes your comment perfectly valid. When I am totally exhausted, I can float on my back until starvation or I can roll on side unintentionally in my maligna. Thanks for pointing this out.